# How do I propertly subscribe to location updates when a View is visible?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've created a class that implements `CLLocationDelegate` and `ObservableObject` so that it can let views subscribe to location updates using `@StateObject` and `@EnvironmentObject`. This works fine, but because only certain views need access to the location, I'd like to call `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` when those views appear or disappear.

Assuming my view has access to the delegate and its location manager, where do I put the `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` calls?

My first inclination was to use `onAppear` and `onDisappear` like so.

```swift
struct ViewThatNeedsLocation : View {
  @EnvironmentObject var locationDelegate: MyLocationDelegate

  var body: some View {
    Text("")
      .onAppear {
        locationDelegate.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
      }.onDisappear {
        locationDelegate.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
      }
  }
}
```

But this suffers from a couple problems:

- `onAppear` and `onDisappear` can be called multiple times due to parent changes, even if the user never sees the view visibly change.
- `onDisappear` is not guaranteed to be called before a subsequent `onAppear` call.

This means I can get the following order of events

```
onAppear
  startUpdatingLocation (good)
onAppear (again)
  startUpdatingLocation (redundant)
onDisappear (?)
  stopUpdatingLocation (bad)
```

My guess is that `ViewThatNeedsLocation` is being created and destroyed multiple times without the rendered content being changed. This would be fine if `SwiftUI` provided some sort of guarantee about the order of the lifecycle modifiers, but it doesn't.

What is the *correct* way to do this? Is there a simple way to fire setup and teardown functions when a view appears and disappears reliably?

Comment: I would say start updating inside init() call, and once you receive location values in model class, there you can stop updating locations.

Comment: But I want the location to update continuously when the View is showing. Stopping when I get the first update will mean I only get a single value.

Comment: Start it upon init and stop it when the user navigates to the next `View`. Like with a custom Back button, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
@Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined
@Published var location: CLLocation?
@Published var region: CLRegion?

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func requestLocation() {
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}

func updateLocation() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func stopUpdatingLocation() {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    self.authorizationStatus = status
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        self.location = location
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("error getting location \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
}
```

And in view struct:

```
 @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
 @State private var location: CLLocation?

    .onReceive(locationManager.$location, perform: userLocation)
    .onReceive(locationManager.$authorizationStatus, perform: { status in
        switch status {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.updateLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.updateLocation()
        default:
            break
        }
    })
```

I just need first location so i am calling locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() in my view in userLocation function, but you can do that in onDisapear.
[here you have some demo](https://github.com/shomi11/FindIt)

Comment: i forgot to mention, if this approach is ok to you, don't forget to import Combine.

Comment: thanks for your answer! unfortunately i need to continuously update the user's location while the view is visible so just getting the location once won't work.